# Non-interactive customization and installation of FreeBSD Ports

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

I'm new to FreeBSD, coming from a Linux background. I want to install a port, changing one of the default configuration options, in a non-interactive way (so that I can script the installation for automated configuration of my FreeBSD servers).

As a specific example, the `graphics/ImageMagick-nox11` port has a default configuration option of `PERL=on`. I want to change this. I realize that I can `make config` and then just use the generated entry in `/var/db/ports/` to avoid any interaction in the future, but this still requires the initial interaction to set the options in the ncurses interface.

Ideally I want to be able to do something like the following, to build the package with perl support disabled but accepting all other defaults:

```
$ make PERL=off BATCH=yes install clean
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this? Can I somehow place port-specific configuration options like this in `/etc/make.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

I think [ports-mgmt/portconf](http://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/portconf/) will do what do you want:

> Portconf is a simple framework to set ports options in an
>   universal way. Knobs set to specific ports are honoured
>   by portmaster, portupgrade, portmanager and 'make install'.

Check more in [pkg-message](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/ports-mgmt/portconf/files/pkg-message.in?view=markup).

Comment: That looks promising, but I don't understand the entry format. Should I do something like `graphics/ImageMagick-nox11: !PERL` in my `ports.conf`?

Comment: I've tried it some time ago but I don't use it - I don't remember but check `pkg-message` as I wrote above.

But I think it will not perfect for you because if you have a port without options in DBDIR, will ask if `portconf` doesn't specify all options.

But one another possibility: ports-mgmt/portmaster. It has `-G` option which prevents `make config`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your `/etc/make.conf`:

```
.if ${.CURDIR:M*/graphics/ImageMagick-nox11}
WITHOUT="PERL"
.endif
```

This checks if the current directory is the `graphics/ImageMagick-nox11` directory and then sets `WITHOUT="PERL"` only when this port is build.

Comment: If I do this `make showconfig` still shows `PERL=on`. Would this not come into effect until I actually `make install`?

Comment: Ahh sorry `WITH_PERL` was the old style. Now its `WITHOUT="PERL, PYTHON..."` or `WITH="PERL, PYTHON..."`.